# Type command not working in Google Colab but woking on local machine

Tags: json, command, geojson, google-colaboratory

!type trn_bf_aoi.geojson | supermercado burn 19 | mercantile shapes | fio collect >trn_bf_tiles.geojson

This file is not creating desired output, it's creating a file with 0kb size, but it's working fine on local machine, can anyone tell where the problem is?

Comment: Please share a self-contained notebook that reproduces the problem you observe.

Comment: Here: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1frnbxCO5i7wQ19PzpEVGIBBY0MpbpKE0

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the contents of "val_bf_aoi.geojson" and ensure that it is not
   empty.
2. If it's not empty, try to use the full path of the file in the last command:
   `'/content/val_bf_aoi.geojson'`

This file is saved inside /content, while using the **Colab cell**. The current directory might be different in the context of **shell**, when you invoke it using exclamation(!).